# Extracting URLs from the tag using Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am pretty new to Java and I have no clue as to how I might extract the parts from Java without using HTML Parser.

Lets assume that I have the following tag:

```
<img width="506" height="200" src="Jozo/image014.png" v:shapes="image_x0020_1" />
```

I would like to extract Jozo/image014.png using regex possibly but it would be great if anyone can assist me with this...

Thank you very much

Comment: It is possible without the parser, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Please don't use regex to extract info from xml format.

Comment: because I will be using it to change the attribute value.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a parser? It's specifically designed to do exactly this, while a regex is not.

Answer (score 2):

Use html Parser `Regex` is not accurate to parse the html content

```
String htmltag = "<img width=\"506\" height=\"200\" src=\"Jozo/image014.png\" "
        + "v:shapes=\"image_x0020_1\" />";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmltag);

Elements ImageUrl = doc.select("img");
for (Element el : ImageUrl)
    System.out.println(el.attr("src"));
```

Comment: uh, you probably want to escape out those quotes so that works.